# set up jQuery test with jsdom, mocha, es2016

Tags: jquery, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm trying to use sinon's fake server to mock a jQuery call in a mocha test. but the test always gives an error like jQuery.post is not a function or that jQuery is undefined. I'm not clear how to import jQuery into jsdom using es6/es2015 syntax.

this is the contents of test/setup.js (a jquery npm package was installed)

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');

global.window = document.defaultView
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.jQuery = jQuery;

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

I assume after setup is fixed, I should just be able to use `jQuery.post()` within the test without changes there.

most of the setup config is coming from http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html

Answer (score 0):

When you load jQuery, it detects whether the global space is a window. If yes, then it exports itself to the window as `jQuery` and `$`. If not, then what it exports as a module value is an *installation function* with which you can install jQuery on future window object. In your original code, by the time `import jQuery from 'jquery';` there is no window yet for jQuery to use, so you get an installation function that you then have to use to install jQuery on the window, once you have it.

Here's code that works. Each line I've added or modified is commented.

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';
import _jQuery from 'jquery'; // Modify this to add the underscore.

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');

global.window = document.defaultView

const jQuery = _jQuery(window); // Add this line.

Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.jQuery = jQuery;

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

// This should output "function".
console.log(typeof jQuery.post);
```